# Windows screen bounds with dual monitors

Tags: powershell, screen-resolution

I am looking to get the total screen resolution using dual monitors in powershell.

```
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
$SCREENWIDTH = [int]$screen.bounds.Size.Width
$SCREENHEIGHT = [int]$screen.bounds.Size.Height
```

With this I get 1920 X 1200 but the resolution is actually 3840 X 1200. I could just double the resolution, however that wont always work depending on the monitors being used.

I am doing this within powershell studio. The reason for knowing this is because sometimes the program opens up off screen, if it does open off screen, I can move it back to the bottom right hand corner.

Answer (score 1):

On the primary Screen the Resolution is still 1920x1200. You can check, how much screens are attached ( `[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens` ) and work with the bounds `[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | select -ExpandProperty bounds`.

Comment: Ok, this is getting me closer. output from that is: 
 {X=1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1200} {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1200} How would I separate that into Height and Width? I have no doubt id be able to get that string into the format I need, however it would be super spaghetti code.

Comment: Check my code with `select -expandproperty bounds`. This will create you an array with both Screens and properties like X,Y, height and width ..

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found works with the help of Martin. But I know it is super sloppy. I may ask another question to try to get this cleaned up.

```
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | select -ExpandProperty bounds
foreach ($item in $screen)
{
    $item = $item -replace ".*Y=0,","" -replace "{", "" -replace "}", "" -replace "Width=", "" -replace "Height=", "" -replace ",", ";"
    $pos = $item.IndexOf(";")
    $leftPart = $item.Substring(0, $pos)
    $rightPart = $item.Substring($pos + 1)
    [int]$SCREENWIDTH = $SCREENWIDTH + $leftPart
    [int]$SCREENHEIGHT = $rightPart
}
$richtextbox1.Text = ([string]$SCREENWIDTH + " " + [string]$SCREENHEIGHT)
```