# Find dual screen resolution

Tags: powershell, screen-resolution

I am looking for a way to get the total resolution on a computer with dual monitors. I have found a way to do this through [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775164/windows-screen-bounds-with-dual-monitors/35775789?noredirect=1#comment59224250_35775789) (this was my question) but the solution I came up with below is super clunky.

```
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | select -ExpandProperty bounds
foreach ($item in $screen)
{
    $item = $item -replace ".*Y=0,","" -replace "{", "" -replace "}", "" -replace "Width=", "" -replace "Height=", "" -replace ",", ";"
    $pos = $item.IndexOf(";")
    $leftPart = $item.Substring(0, $pos)
    $rightPart = $item.Substring($pos + 1)
    [int]$SCREENWIDTH = $SCREENWIDTH + $leftPart
    [int]$SCREENHEIGHT = $rightPart
}
$richtextbox1.Text = ([string]$SCREENWIDTH + " " + [string]$SCREENHEIGHT)
```

The output from:

```
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | select -ExpandProperty bounds
```

is

```
{X=1920,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1200} {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1200}
```

The desired output is to have the total width and height stored to variables.

I am using powershell studio.

Answer (score 0):

## Just make sure you initialize $screenwidth

```
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | select -ExpandProperty bounds
$SCREENWIDTH = 0
foreach ($item in $screen)
{
    $item = $item -replace ".*Y=0,","" -replace "{", "" -replace "}", "" -replace "Width=", "" -replace "Height=", "" -replace ",", ";"
    $pos = $item.IndexOf(";")
    $leftPart = $item.Substring(0, $pos)
    $rightPart = $item.Substring($pos + 1)

    [int]$SCREENWIDTH = $SCREENWIDTH + $leftPart
    [int]$SCREENHEIGHT = $rightPart
}

([string]$SCREENWIDTH + " " + [string]$SCREENHEIGHT)
```